# 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate' Error

Tags: powershell, x509certificate, x509

I am new to PowerShell and am trying to write a URL extension brute-force tool. My current target that I am testing against is a SharePoint site. I can manually, using a browser, go to the default homepage (the only URL I am currently testing against), but I get a 401 status code when I try from my script.

Here is my code:

```
#$d equals the domain name for the website
#$i equals the input location and filename for the url list
#$o equals the output location and filename for the output

param(
[parameter(mandatory=$true)]
[validatenotnull()]
$d = $(throw "please provide the domain of the target URL. Ex https://www.google.com"),
[parameter(mandatory=$true]
[validatenotnull()]
$i = $(throw "Please provide the path to the file listing the URL extensions."),
[string]
$o
)

$date = (get-date -format MM-dd-yy)
$cert = (get-childitem cert: -recurse | where {$_ -is [system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2]})

if ($o -eq "") {
    $o = $date+"_output.txt"
    new-item -path .\ -name $o -type file
}

cls

get-content $i |
foreach-object {
    try {invoke-webrequest -url $d$_ -certificate $cert -method head -maximumredirection 0}
    catch {"error - $_"}
    echo ($_)
    echo ""
    echo "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
} | tee -a $o
```

The error I am getting back is the following:

```
Error - Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate' required by parameter 'Certificate'. Specified method is not supported.
```

I am running windows 7 and PowerShell v3.

Comment: `get-childitem cert: -recurse` returns a collection of all matches so you need to extract the one(s) you want to use.

Comment: How do I identify which cert I want. I have tried giving the path cert:\currentuser\my and also the actual fingerprint for one cert in that directory. When I identify only 1 cert with a fingerprint I no longer get the convert error, but am still getting a 401 status code. Is there another way to grab the cert without hard coding a fingerprint?